# Is it possible to adjust left hand side height of cardview?

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview, cardview

I have a CardView aligned to the top of the screen. Inside the CardView, there is an ImageView and I just want to adjust the height of the right-hand side of the CardView just like in the image below. Is this possible?

[image]

```
  <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="1"
  app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.4"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  app:cardElevation="10dp"
  app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">
    <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/bngCover"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/explore2"
       android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asides the radius, CardViews are usually rectangular in nature; therefore, **this cannot be easily achieved with a CardView**.

Best advice would be to create your own resource file. This way, you can define how exactly you want your view to look and still give it the properties you want (elevation, radius, etc).

To learn how to create a drawable resource file, check [this tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-shape-drawables-tutorial-17fbece6fef5) out. You can also read up on the Android documentation on ShapeDrawables [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ShapeDrawable.html).

Answer (score 0):

CardView doesn't have the property to change on side height only. In this case, you must create a custom trapezoid shape instead, like this:

[How to build trapezoid shape in xml android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501129/how-to-build-trapezoid-shape-in-xml-android)